# get property values using ngcheck in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a `li`, user can select items, and each item has property of url, which in the end it the system could store them.

in my case I couldn't ng-true-value because my checkbox's ng-model has been occupied due to other logics.

the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/p1fBW3swPHnyBQGBD6Xj?p=preview

I want to get the selected url and alert it.

Comment: can user select multiple values?

Comment: @wickY26 yes, that's the point I put checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix checkbox binding:

```
  <input ng-show="showC || checked" type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
```

Should be:

```
  <input ng-show="showC || checked" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
```

And get all checked items in the `getLinks` function:

```
  $scope.getlinks = function(){
    var urls = '';
    angular.forEach($scope.lists, function(item){
      if(item.checked === true){
        urls += item.url + '\n';
      }
    });

    alert("selected Links: " + urls);
  };
```

Comment: what if I want to open those links? I tried  if(item.checked === true){
            $window.open(item.url);
        }

Comment: it seem blocked by browser popup